# ImageJ macro code to change directory

Tags: macros, imagej

I am learning how to write macros in ImageJ. I have the user select a folder where data is stored, e.g.,

```bs
path=getDirectory("Choose a data folder");
```

Once the user has selected the folder, e.g.,

```
path = D:\data_superfolder\data_folder
```

I then need to access a file that is up one level, e.g.,

```
newpath = D:\data_superfolder
```

In Matlab to move up one level all i need to do is,

```
cd('..')
```

which is super simple, but I've read through the ImageJ user manual I can't find similar code. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append `/..` to a directory path to refer to its parent folder.

Here is an example macro that prompts the user to choose a directory, then lists the contents of its parent.

```
path = getDirectory("Choose a folder");
list = getFileList(path + "/..");
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    print(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,
But I can't get it to work:

path = getDirectory("Choose folder")
superpath= path+"\..";
run("Open...", "open = ["+superpath+"image.tif"+"]

errors with: 
File is not in a supported format, a reader plugin is not available, or it was not found.
F:\Data\2015-04-02\..image.tif

It just added two dots between the end of the folder and the file name, but I want it to change directories to find the image file in "F:\Data", and open it after the user selects the data folder for a specific experiment date. 

Thanks!

Comment: Your path would need to be `F:\Data\2015-04-02\..\image.tif`. That is, there must be a slash separating the `..` and the filename. Try using `superpath+"\image.tif"` instead.

Comment: OK, adding the backslash helped, but I had to use two:

F:\Data\2015-04-09\..\\image.tif

And then it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: Good point; backslash is the escape character, so you have to write "\\" to mean one literal backslash. This is why I suggested you use forward slash instead (/), since that works on all platforms including Windows, and avoids that issue.

Comment: I see, I use both matlab and imageJ and I use the backslash exclusively and I was just trying to be consistent. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had a similar problem, tried the fix suggested here and I couldn't get it to work... However, what worked for me was to **define a new variable corresponding to the parent of your initial input directory, using the function File.getParent().**

in example:

```
path = getDirectory("Choose a folder");
parent_path = File.getParent(path);
list = getFileList(parent_path);

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
print(list[i]);
}
```

so in your case, once the user has selected the folder, e.g.,

```
path = D:\data_superfolder\data_folder
```

the variable "parent_path" will be:

```
parent_path = D:\data_superfolder
```

Cheers!